# Call WCF service from a background thread

Tags: multithreading, wcf

I’m working on a piece of code which would take in an API request to a WebAPI controller and through that invoke a WCF web service. This would block until the WCF service responded and cause issues such as timeouts and performance problems. I can't use async/await for this particular use case for a number of reasons beyond my control.

I’m looking at kicking this WCF call off on a separate thread, so in the WebAPI controller I do something like:

```
New Thread(()=>{
    //Call WCF service here
    //Do something with the response
}).Start();
```

However, the code is blowing up. The line that calls the WCF service was moved into the above codeblock unchanged, but now I’m getting:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel'.

Looking at the stack trace when the exception is thrown, I can see the server stack trace as follows:

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrImmutable()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel
>   channel, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Im not hugely experienced with WCF so wondered if there was some quirk regarding calling this service in a background thread or if there was something else I needed to do instead?

I’ve tried Googling this but all the results are pertaining to calling a background thread from *within* a WCF service, not calling a WCF service *from* a background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out in the end. It was a Unity problem. For some reason, whereas the existing code was:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyServiceWrapper, MyServiceImplementation>()
```

I had to explicitly tell Unity how to resolve the constructor parameter:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyServiceWrapper, MyServiceImplementation>(
   new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IMyDependentService>()));
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea why this was required or why it fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much sure, that you creating instance of WCF service outside thread. So previously it looked like:

```
using(var client = new WcfServiceClient())
{
    client.CallSomeMethod();
}
```

And you changed it to something like:

```
using(var client = new WcfServiceClient())
{
    new Thread(() => {
        client.CallSomeMethod();
    }).Start();
}
```

And what you need to is to move client creation into Thread:

```
    new Thread(() => {
        using(var client = new WcfServiceClient())
        {
            client.CallSomeMethod();
        }
    }).Start();
}
```